# Objective-C - why adding two string is causing the crash?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Appending new string to old string is causing crash. 
(abnormally works if i do as like this `StructIOS.server = @""; StructIOS.server = [StructIOS.server stringByAppendingString:@".stackoverflow.com"];`).

struct.h:

```
struct iOS {
  __unsafe_unretained NSString *input_url;
  __unsafe_unretained NSString *use_url;  
  __unsafe_unretained NSString *server;
};
struct iOS StructIOS;
```

ViewController.m:

```
StructIOS.use_url = @"relay/pincode/apicode/accesskey/1/2/3/99/../900";
NSArray *work_array = [StructIOS.use_url componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
StructIOS.server    = [work_array objectAtIndex:0];
if([StructIOS.server length] > 0) {
  NSLog(@">>> 4: %@", StructIOS.server); // OK!!
  StructIOS.server = [StructIOS.server stringByAppendingString:@".stackoverflow.com"]; // FAIL!!
  NSLog(@">>> 5: %@", StructIOS.server);  
}
```

**Output:**

```
>>> 4: relay
crash
```

**Expected output:**

```
>>> 5: relay.stackoverflow.com
```

**EDIT:** following way worked without crash

```
NSString *fool_ios;

// read from NSString type
StructIOS.server = fool_ios;

// save to NSString type
fool_ios = StructIOS.server;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are they __unsafe_unretailed? 
componentsSeparatedByString() will presumably internally be creating some substrings which you are not taking ownership of due to using __unsafe_unretained, thus they are being deleted when componentsSeparatedByString function got out of scope.
The log at line 4 is working purely though chance and good luck as the string is deallocated but still there at that memory location.
If you rewrite the struct as a simple class (which inherits from NSObject) it should work.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/BfaoqfM.png - When i remove that i get compile error: `/Users/sun/Desktop/iphone/Objective-C_ios10/ios-demo/Struct.h:11:13: ARC forbids Objective-C objects in struct`

Comment: Actually ARC forbids objective-c objects in a struct, so you should rewrite the struct as  a simple class.

Comment: OK - so its core Objective-C issue. thank you,  i will.

Comment: You also might want to do things like enable malloc scribble and zombies in the Xcode settings which can help detect things like this (if you just used StructIOS.server somewhere without appending to it you would not have discovered the problem, until it crashes randomly somewhere, malloc scribble and zombies etc. will help detect it early). These options are available in the build scheme.

Comment: OK thank you. (Awkward when i do this it works `NSString *fool_ios = [StructIOS.server stringByAppendingString:@".stackoverflow.com"]; StructIOS.server = fool_ios;` )

Comment: @YumYumYum The trouble is, you were advised _twice_ on your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677370/objective-c-is-it-possible-to-have-nsarray-in-my-struct _not_ to have objects in a C struct, and you didn't listen.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is two-fold:

- Don't store objects in Objective-C Structs. ARC won't manage the memory for them.
- Don't use unsafe_unretained unless you understand exactly what it does and exactly why you need it.

Simply make your variables instance variables of your class. That will make them strong, which is what you want.

### EDIT:

Note that in Swift, it is valid to store objects in a Struct. Swift is able to memory manage them inside a struct, where C does not.

Any time the compiler forces you to use __unsafe_unretained, you're likely doing something wrong. (There are exceptions to that, but at your level of understanding, you should pretend that __unsafe_unretained doesn't exist.)